# Jquery display images one after another

Tags: jquery

This is perhaps a couple of questions rolled into one here, I am creating an image gallery and wanted the thumbnails to fade in on the page one after another, this needs to be dynamic to the amount of images within a div (for reuse on the other gallery pages)

```
$(function {
var $gallImages = $('#galleryThumbs img');


for(i=0; i<=$gallImages.length; i++){
    $(document.getElementById('galleryThumbs').getElementsByTagName('img')[i]).addClass('done').fadeIn('slow');

}});
```

This displays the images all at the same time on load:(

Also is there a better way to do element collection in jQuery I couldn't find anything about using the array needed  for the image tags

Any help on this would be appreciated, am hitting a mental block on this

Comment: $('#galleryThumbs img'); What does the above mean? All images having the id "galleryThumbs"? Can i have same ID in different image tags? If so what is the use of specifying same id in different tags?

Comment: @lax - this means, get me all images inside the element with an id of `galleryThumbs`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can just add a [`.delay()`](http://api.jquery.com/delay/) to each, like this:

```
$(function {
  $('#galleryThumbs img').each(function(i) {
    $(this).delay(i*600).fadeIn('slow')
  });
});
```

I'm not sure when your class should be added though, you can do it immediately or [`.queue()`](http://api.jquery.com/queue/) it, depending on  if it should happen just before the fade.  This fades in the first immediately, the second 600ms later (when the first fade finishes), the next after that, etc.  If you want overlap just lower that `600` (which is what `'slow'` is).

To add the class immediately, fade one by one:

```
$('#galleryThumbs img').addClass('done').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i*600).fadeIn('slow')
});
```

Or, to add it just before fading:

```
$('#galleryThumbs img').each(function(i) {
  $(this).delay(i*600).queue(function(n) { $(this).addClass('done'); n(); })
                      .fadeIn('slow')
});
```

Comment: Hi, ah cool makes sense, only I get a syntax error on this, 'Delay is not a function'

Comment: @user499846 -are you using a capital `D`? it's case-sensitive :) If you are sing lower-case, which version of jQuery are you on?

Comment: I am using jquery-1.4.3.min.js

Comment: @user499846 -are you using `.Delay()` or `.delay()`?

Comment: Hi, sorry not sure what happened there, I cleared my cache and restarted my browser and the error disappeared!, thanks for your help!!

Comment: @NickCraver hey sir I have similar problem like above https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56521258/how-to-display-image-dynamically-on-ui  it is bit different can you please check it once