# Fade in an image and after the effect finishes, fade in another next to it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I understand the rules of SO that I must search first in similar questions for the answer, but none of them in the topic got what I'm looking for. I'm trying to make a div that has an image on it fade in, and after it finishes that effect then another one fades in next to it. I'm pretty sure it has to be done with jQuery callbacks, but everything that I've tried doesn't seem to work.

Here is the HTML and the jQuery:

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(".responsive").fadeIn(2500).removeClass("responsive", function() {
    $(".responsive2").fadeIn(5000).removeClass("responsive2");
  });
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="w3-row">
  <div class="w3-col s6 w3-center">
    <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/237/100" class="responsive">
    <a href="lu-sound.html">
      <h1 class="center left">SOUND</h1>
    </a>
  </div>
  <div class="w3-row">
    <div class="w3-col s6 w3-center">
      <img src="https://picsum.photos/id/1062/100" class="responsive2">
      <a href="lu-suspension.html">
        <h1 class="center right">SUSPENSION</h1>
      </a>
    </div>
  </div>
```

The CSS is simple:
Both classes, .responsive and .responsive2 have a display property of none.

Comment: This is probably a duplicate. Check out this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/4117876/2434539

Comment: While it looks like a duplicate, the accepted answer is either outdated or could be improved for this scenario.

Answer (score 1):

Your thinking seems to be ok, but check your code again, you have the callback for `removeClass`, but it has to be for `fadeIn`.

```
$(".responsive").fadeIn(2500, function() {
    //callback
}).removeClass("responsive");
```

Comment: Yeah, about two hours ago I understood the callback needed to be for the fadein, but I didn't know how to write it. I just used @freedomn-m's answer it worked.

Answer (score 1):

Most of the jquery animation functions have two parameters: duration and [on]complete.  You can use this second parameter to 'continue' with the next animation, ie:

```
$(function() { 
    $(".responsive").fadeIn(2500, function() { 
        $(this).removeClass("responsive");
        $(".responsive2").fadeIn(5000, function() { 
            $(this).removeClass("responsive2");
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: This was the answer I was looking for. I almost got to it on my own, as I did write that third line with the $(this) but then I got stuck, didn't know I was missing so little. Thank you. This is my third question on SO, how do I close this question as solved or anything like that?

Comment: I've never asked a question so can't be precise, but there should be an option similar to "accept as answer" - it might not be available immediately to give other people time to provide answers.   You can also upvote any question you found useful (not just the one you used).